# if else .htaccess/ISAPI

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting, isapi, if-statement

I would like to check a URL to see if it contains one of multiple strings, and then based on that, send it to a different URL. Am I forced to use multiple lines, one for each possibility? Or is there anyway to form an if statement? I figured that something like this should work:

(string1)(string2)(string3) example.com/$1$2$3

because in my case, multiple strings will never be found, so the extra strings will be NULL in the redirected URL. however, that only works if I want to use the string itself as the modified part of the new URL, which I do not.

At what file size do I need to start worrying about my file load time?

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: let me make it a bit more clear sorry - say string1 matches, I want string1 to be associated with an irrelevant URL, say string1 sends me to flikr, string2 sends me to gmail. the new URL has nothing to do (address-wise) with the matched string

Answer (score 2):

You can use simple alternation in your regular expression:

```
RewriteRule ^/(string1|string2|string3)$ http://example.com/$1
```

This would match the paths `/string1`, `/string2` or `/string3`.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want something more like this:

```
RewriteRule string1|string2|string3 example.com/$0
```

The expression `string1|string2|string3` in the regex matches any of the three alternatives, and `$0` is of course replaced with whatever the entire regular expression matched.